# Checking if one polytope is contained in another

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, linear-programming, computational-geometry

I have two sets of inequalities, say, $Ax \leq 0$ and $Bx \leq 0$. I would like to know if they both define the same polytope. Or, even, whether one is contained in the other.

At the moment I am checking, for each row $a \in A$, whether there exists some $x$ satisfying $ax > 0$ but $Bx \leq 0$. Is there a more efficient approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would like to draw your attention to the 2002 survey by Volker Kaibel and Marc Pfetsch,
"Some Algorithmic Problems in Polytope Theory," [arXiv:math/0202204v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202204), which contains this on p.6:

 
[image: KP Problems]

As you probably know, an $\cal{H}$-description is by halfspaces, whereas a $\cal{V}$-description is by vertices.
Reference [20] is: R. M. Freund and J. B. Orlin, "On the complexity of four polyhedral set
containment problems," *Math. Program.*, 33 (1985), pp. 139–145.
Reference [17] is B. C. Eaves and R. M. Freund, "Optimal scaling of balls and polyhedra," *Math. Program.*, 23 (1982), pp. 138–147.